# Consolation badges for hitting the reputation cap hard

Tags: discussion, badges, daily-reputation-limit

**Edit:** I forgot about the Nice Answer badges that situation almost certainly incurs, ignore this question from now on.

Although I'm on a good way toward an 'Epic' badge on Stack Overflow, I still get a warm fuzzy when I hit the daily reputation cap; that is, if I don't get hit by it too hard. The cap is somewhat frustrating on days with more than 30 or so upvotes, and today (still four and a half hours to go), I stand at 54 upvotes and one accept, for 215 reputation points. I'm not too happy with the cap at the moment.

So I thought it would be a nice consolation if at least there was a badge for suffering hard from the cap, maybe a silver badge (Great Day) for 40 or 50 upvotes on a single day and a gold badge (Awesome Day) for 100 or 150?

Perhaps the count should be limited to answers/questions not older than 7, 14 or 30 days so it's not an automatic badge once you have enough questions and answers overall.

What do you think?

(This is a discussion for the moment; it could become a feature request.)

Comment: That would almost double Jon Skeet's current number of (silver?) badges...

Comment: When you hit the cap, you're suppose to go outside and breathe fresh air.

Comment: @LarsTech "*Outside*"... "*fresh air*"? What are these things of which you speak? I'm gonna go ask Jon Skeet... he'll know! :D

Comment: @AndrewBarber: He means the really big conference room with the blue ceiling and the one really bright light.

Comment: Do we *really* need to give Jon Skeet more props?

Comment: Are you Jon Skeet?  No?  Then you didn't hit the reputation cap "hard".

Comment: Jon Skeet has no reputation cap.  The Stack Exchange voting system simply can't keep up with him.  (Sorry, had to.  It's a fun meme.)

Comment: Not Mohs 10, but hard enough to make me cringe. I'm a wimp.

Comment: @Won't Yeah!  Why not?  =P

Comment: @Won't I was actually sort of insulting him, good-naturedly. :P Kinda.

Comment: Remember that this site is not only about Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are already badges for questions/answers that get very high vote counts, and as you note, there is a badge for getting lots of reputation for lots of days. (multiple levels of badges for each, actually).

As a result, I think a badge such as you note would be a little bit redundant.

Comment: Right, forgot about the Nice Answer badges that almost certainly brings.

Comment: Yup; Nice Answer, Good Answer, and Great Answer. [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert?tab=badges) earned all three for a question yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

Badges are intended to encourage behavior that helps the system. I don't see how this encourages good or desired behavior.

The reputation cap is partially intended to encourage people to come back frequently for short bursts of activity, rather than binge infrequently.  This badge would, to some degree, negate that and encourage people to binge.

Comment: I also think it helps to somewhat limit the effect of some off-the-wall question/answer becoming viral in nature, and getting huge up votes in a short period of time.