# Badges for significantly exceeding the daily reputation cap, excluding bounties

Tags: discussion, badges, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consolation badges for hitting the reputation cap hard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119524/consolation-badges-for-hitting-the-reputation-cap-hard)

I got excited today when I hit 305 rep for the day on SO (first time above 300). Unfortunately, somebody has unaccepted an answer and I'm back to 290 :-(

Anyway, would it not be fun to add badges (awarded once only) when hitting specific daily reputation levels, excluding bounties? For example, the levels could be:

- 200 => bronze = Mortarboard - already exists
- 300 => silver = ...
- 450 => gold = ... (this one is for Jon Skeet & Darin Dimitrov only)

I'm not good at names, but I'm sure someone can come up with an idea.

I think these represent real achievements, similarly to the epic / legendary badges, except that they can be obtained in one (admittedly busy) day.

Comment: I'd prefer a badge for getting X votes over the repcap... "You've lost 2000 rep today to the repcap, here's a cookie. :)"

Comment: Anyways, I think this was proposed before. I just need to find that dupe.

Comment: I love the repcap lossage badge proposal. It should be called "Kneecapped".

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good idea. It would encourage users to participate even after they achieved the maximum rep cap. However, I think 450 rep points in a day is too low for a gold badge. Perhaps increase it to 500.

Here are some badge names:

**Silver**

- Activist
- Busy Day

**Gold**

- No Work Done
- Sung Hero

Comment: +1 for "no work done" ;-)

Comment: I am serious about "Kneecapped".

Answer (score -1):

That'd be somewhat against repcap ideology itself. It was introduced, so users with big backlog of answers and activity won't get overwhelmingly high reputation every day. With your proposal exactly same users will just get badges instead.

Comment: Well yes, but only once and I don't think there are that many users who will get the gold badge actually.

Comment: Yes, not many. But still exactly those who were capped in first place. "We already know you're great from rep, here, have a free badge."

Comment: To be honest, I don't think they will care so much or that it would be a problem, but for normal users, it could be a great incentive / reward.